# SendGrid 401 Error - Java API

Tags: java, macos, environment-variables, sendgrid

When I try to send the email, I get the error:

```
Request returned status Code 401Body:{"errors":[{"message":"The provided authorization grant is invalid, expired, or revoked","field":null,"help":null}]}
```

When I try

```
System.out.println("API Key is " + System.getenv("SENDGRID_API_KEY"));
```

I get

```
API Key is null
```

So, clearly the `SENDGRID_API_KEY` env variable is not set properly. I'm using Mac OSX for my dev environment. I tried to set the env variable as you have advised in the docs:

```
echo "export SENDGRID_API_KEY='YOUR_API_KEY'" > sendgrid.env
echo "sendgrid.env" >> .gitignore
source ./sendgrid.env
```

When I type `echo $SENDGRID_API_KEY` on the terminal, it shows a blank line.

Answer (score -1):

System.out.println("API Key is " + System.getenv(SENDGRID_API_KEY));

Comment: The solution presented doesn't answer the question.